# raspberry pi power

Tags: power-supply

I have a VEX 393 motor and was wondering if there was any way that I could hook it up to a raspberry pi and if so how many extra voltage is needed to add to the ground prong (provide diagram if possible)
also if anyone else has any info on any better ways to run this motor please feel free to tell me them because I may need a better way of running these that is more power efficient and runs a little faster than what the Pi would (the Pi would be rather useful though) if anyone has any questions for me regarding my question please feel free to ask them

Comment: Do you have any research at all?

Comment: yes I have a full 40 page doc on my research

Comment: Specifics help. What are you stuck on?

Comment: how to program the motor, I am pretty new to python

Comment: @ThomasSmith: Why not include a link to the manual in your question? You haven't said whether it's DC, AC, stepper, servo, or what. You haven't given any specs for voltage or current. There's an edit link under your question ... Raspberry and Pi get capital letters.

Comment: I dont understand what the AC,DC,Stepper,servo, or what part of your question, sorry

Comment: The motor connects directly to 2-Wire Motor Ports (Ports 1 & 10 on the Cortex Microcontroller). For 3-Wire Motor Ports (Ports 2-9 on the Cortex), a Motor Controller 29 must be used in between the Microcontroller and the motor.

Comment: Each of the motor and pi should have its own power supply, with a common ground if the situation is quiet or with opto isolation if not.  Also a pi is a bad choice for motor control - too complex, too busy doing other things, and too fragile in its  hardware, software, and storage.

Comment: these are helpful but can anyone include a pic of the coding for me to use?

Comment: Do you really need to use the Pi?  Sounds from a comment that a simple manual switch or pushbutton (and battery) may be all you need.

Comment: the classroom teacher wants us to use a Pi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've head over to the VEX website and found this regarding your product:

[image]

Voltage is directly proportional to angular velocity and we know that at 7.2v (says it on the site) we have 100RPM. 100RPM = \$\frac{10}{3}\pi\$ rad/s

Which means we have \$V = k_{v}\omega\$, therefore \$7.2 = k_{v} \cdot \frac{10}{3}\pi\$ solving for k gives \$k_{v}\approx 0.69\$ Volts/rad/s

The same thing applies to the current, but this time with torque instead of angular velocity \$I = k_{i}\tau\$, since \$4.8 = k_{i} \cdot 1.67\$ solving for k gives \$k_{i}\approx 2.87\$ A/Nm

This helps you out determine how much power you want depending on your objective, this is because power is angular velocity times torque, i.e, \$P = \tau\omega = VI\eta\$ where \$\eta\$ is the efficiency. Since voltage is a function of angular velocity and current is a function of torque, we can solve for the efficiency: \$\frac{10}{3}\pi \cdot 1.67 = \frac{10}{3}\pi \cdot 0.69 \cdot 1.67 \cdot 2.87 \cdot \eta\$ yields \$\eta \approx 0.51\$ the motor seems to be 51% efficient.

For the vast majority of cases the raspberry pi won't be a sufficient power source, (just look at max settings, 100 rpm and 1.67Nm is around 34W of electrical power due to the efficiency of the motor, your pi will never output that amount of power) you'll have to connect it to a mosfet transistor in order to drive the motor via a different source. You can use pwm from the raspberry pi to drive the gate of the mosfet, thus allowing you to modify the required speed and power.

Simple schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdXZsk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You can also use gears to decrease rpm and increase torque, the opposite can also be done.

Comment: thanks this actually helps me out because in the class I need this for I am trying to pull a string to launch a bottle rocket to reduce the amount of people who get wet

Comment: it also reduces the chance for human eror because I cut my finger tryign to pull the sleeve off the rocket  dident feel good lol